# Show/Hide Polylinedecorators dynamically (based on other variable) in React Leaflet (using a for loop)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polyline-decorator

I have succesfully implemented Polylinedecorators, but I am not able to easily hide them based on a boolean statement in React Leaflet. 'Normal' polylines are displayed/hided based on a certain variable (for example the boolean 'certainBool'). I can not seem to find an easy way to easily add polyLineDecorators as a JSX component directly, without using the `addToMap` functionality. The problem with the `addToMap` functionality is that it is difficult to remove the elements added to the map in this way. Especially as my polylines (and polylinedecorators) are created in a (large) for loop. See the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Polyline, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet-polylinedecorator';
import L from 'leaflet';

function showTrajectories() {
  const { trajectories, certainBool } = React.useContext(certainContext);

  const arrow = [
    {
      offset: '52%',
      endOffset: '52%',
      repeat: '100%',
      symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({
        pixelSize: 3,
        polygon: false,
        pathOptions: { stroke: true, opacity: 0.4 },
      }),
    },
  ];


  function PolylineDecorator({ patterns, polyline, id }) {
    const map = useMap();

    var decorator = L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
      id: id,
      patterns,
    });
    decorator.addTo(map);
    return null;
  }

  if (trajectories.length > 0) {
    return trajectories.map((trajectory, i) => {
      if (certainBool) {
        return (
          <>
            <PolylineDecorator polyline={trajectory.coordinates} patterns={arrow} id={i} />
            <Polyline
              positions={trajectory.coordinates}
              className='line'
              key={i}
              noClip={true}
            ></Polyline>
          </>
        );
      }
    });
  }
}

export default showTrajectories;
```